# Google analytics account ios configuration

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to configure google analytics `GoogleService-info.plist` file from [google developers site](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add). Yesterday i configured one app and had no problem. but today i can not configure my second app to use google Analytics.  I Choose **App Name** and **IOS Bundle Id**. Then on next step, where it asks to choose service , i choose **Analytics** , but under **Google Analytics Account** there is no select box to choose account. how can i fix this?

[image]

Comment: Does the account your are logged in with have a Google Analytics account?

Comment: yes, it has Google Analytics account

Comment: I'm having this exact problem, and can't find any useful information.  I have 5 accounts inside google analytics, which were set up for various websites I've run over the years.  One seems to be the default.  The child properties of that default account are the ones that appear on the page where you create your GoogleService-Info.plist file.  Is there anywhere else that you can create this file manually and map it to a different Account's profile?

Comment: my solution was to register new account and make everything with it... so we ended in very funny situation at office.. even our guard has now google account :)

Answer (score 1):

For me I couldn't choose the account because it was pre-filled in. I followed the advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34407859/796490) and it worked. I saw the dropdown after going into the Google Analytics Admin tab --> The Account in question --> User Management and removing myself as a user for that account. Then back where you get the config file, just reload the page and you should see a dropdown. Once you get the file you can put yourself back as a user and all is back to normal.